# Issue updating select value based upon change of another (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two time selects on my webpage. #tStartSelect (00:00, 01:00 ... 23:00), and #tEndSelect (01:00, 02:00 ... 00:00).

I'm trying to write a function which, upon change of value of either select will automatically change the other to +-1hr, making it impossible for the user to pick a 'negative' time-span.

It seems to work for a few selections but then starts allowing negative time-spans. E.g. (changed box in bold):

00:00 to **11:00**

**13:00** to 14:00

07:00 to **08:00**

**14:00** to 15:00

08:00 to **09:00**

**14:00** to 09:00 (negative time-span)

I'm very new to programming so any help would be great, thanks!

Code:

```js
$(document).on('change', '#tStartSelect', function() {
  timeSelectAdjust('start');
});
$(document).on('change', '#tEndSelect', function() {
  timeSelectAdjust('end');
});

var timeSelectAdjust = function(startEnd) {
  var startVal = parseInt($('#tStartSelect').val());
  var endVal = parseInt($('#tEndSelect').val());
  if (startEnd === 'start') {
    if (startVal >= endVal) {
      $('#tEndSelect option[value=' + (startVal + 4) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  } else if (startEnd === 'end') {
    if (endVal <= startVal) {
      $('#tStartSelect option[value=' + (endVal - 4) + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="t_Start">
  <select id="tStartSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="2">00:00</option>
    <option value="6">01:00</option>
    <option value="10">02:00</option>
    <option value="14">03:00</option>
    <option value="18">04:00</option>
    <option value="22">05:00</option>
    <option value="26">06:00</option>
    <option value="30">07:00</option>
    <option value="34">08:00</option>
    <option value="38">09:00</option>
    <option value="42">10:00</option>
    <option value="46">11:00</option>
    <option value="50">12:00</option>
    <option value="54">13:00</option>
    <option value="58">14:00</option>
    <option value="62">15:00</option>
    <option value="66">16:00</option>
    <option value="70">17:00</option>
    <option value="74">18:00</option>
    <option value="78">19:00</option>
    <option value="82">20:00</option>
    <option value="86">21:00</option>
    <option value="90">22:00</option>
    <option value="94">23:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="t_End">
  <select id="tEndSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="6">01:00</option>
    <option value="10">02:00</option>
    <option value="14">03:00</option>
    <option value="18">04:00</option>
    <option value="22">05:00</option>
    <option value="26">06:00</option>
    <option value="30">07:00</option>
    <option value="34">08:00</option>
    <option value="38">09:00</option>
    <option value="42">10:00</option>
    <option value="46">11:00</option>
    <option value="50">12:00</option>
    <option value="54">13:00</option>
    <option value="58">14:00</option>
    <option value="62">15:00</option>
    <option value="66">16:00</option>
    <option value="70">17:00</option>
    <option value="74">18:00</option>
    <option value="78">19:00</option>
    <option value="82">20:00</option>
    <option value="86">21:00</option>
    <option value="90">22:00</option>
    <option value="94">23:00</option>
    <option value="98">00:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated to include parseInt() thanks to @Armel. Question changed to reflect residing issue.

Initial question here...

"I have two time selects on my webpage. #tStartSelect (00:00, 01:00 ... 23:00), and #tEndSelect (01:00, 02:00 ... 00:00).

I'm trying to write a function which, upon change of value of either select will automatically change the other to +-1hr, making it impossible for the user to pick a 'negative' time-span.

For some reason, with the code below, it successfully updates #tStartSelect, but not vice versa. I'm very new to programming so any help would be great, thanks!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert your `string` into `integer` first, otherwise, you will concatenate the text instead of adding values.

```
var startVal = parseInt($('#tStartSelect').val());
var endVal = parseInt($('#tEndSelect').val());
```

It works the other one way around because you subtract a value so there is no concatenation in this case.

```js
$(document).on('change', '#tStartSelect', function() {
  timeSelectAdjust('start');
});
$(document).on('change', '#tEndSelect', function() {
  timeSelectAdjust('end');
});

var timeSelectAdjust = function(startEnd) {
  var startVal = parseInt($('#tStartSelect').val());
  var endVal = parseInt($('#tEndSelect').val());
  if (startEnd === 'start') {
    if (startVal >= endVal) {
      $('#tEndSelect').find('option').attr('selected', false);
      $('#tEndSelect option[value=' + (startVal + 4) + ']').attr('selected', true);
    }
  } else if (startEnd === 'end') {
    if (endVal <= startVal) {
      $('#tStartSelect').find('option').attr('selected', false);
      $('#tStartSelect option[value=' + (endVal - 4) + ']').attr('selected', true);
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="t_Start">
  <select id="tStartSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="2">00:00</option>
    <option value="6">01:00</option>
    <option value="10">02:00</option>
    <option value="14">03:00</option>
    <option value="18">04:00</option>
    <option value="22">05:00</option>
    <option value="26">06:00</option>
    <option value="30">07:00</option>
    <option value="34">08:00</option>
    <option value="38">09:00</option>
    <option value="42">10:00</option>
    <option value="46">11:00</option>
    <option value="50">12:00</option>
    <option value="54">13:00</option>
    <option value="58">14:00</option>
    <option value="62">15:00</option>
    <option value="66">16:00</option>
    <option value="70">17:00</option>
    <option value="74">18:00</option>
    <option value="78">19:00</option>
    <option value="82">20:00</option>
    <option value="86">21:00</option>
    <option value="90">22:00</option>
    <option value="94">23:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div class="t_End">
  <select id="tEndSelect" class="form-control">
    <option value="6">01:00</option>
    <option value="10">02:00</option>
    <option value="14">03:00</option>
    <option value="18">04:00</option>
    <option value="22">05:00</option>
    <option value="26">06:00</option>
    <option value="30">07:00</option>
    <option value="34">08:00</option>
    <option value="38">09:00</option>
    <option value="42">10:00</option>
    <option value="46">11:00</option>
    <option value="50">12:00</option>
    <option value="54">13:00</option>
    <option value="58">14:00</option>
    <option value="62">15:00</option>
    <option value="66">16:00</option>
    <option value="70">17:00</option>
    <option value="74">18:00</option>
    <option value="78">19:00</option>
    <option value="82">20:00</option>
    <option value="86">21:00</option>
    <option value="90">22:00</option>
    <option value="94">23:00</option>
    <option value="98">00:00</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey @Armel, thanks so much for taking the time to look at this. That definitely explains why it works for one way and not the other. Unfortunately, there is still some bug with your example. It is still possible to select an end-time that is earlier than the start-time.

To recreate the scenario, try selecting 'illegal' time-spans a few times. It works the first couple of tries and then stops working. Particularly, it seems when you set #tEndSelect to 08:00 oddly.

Comment: Example...
00:00 - **11:00**,
**13:00** - 14:00,
07:00 - **08:00**,
**14:00** - 15:00,
08:00 - **09:00**,
**14:00** - 09:00

Comment: I see, you have to clear the previous selected option with `$('#tEndSelect').find('option').attr('selected', false);`, I fixed it.

Comment: Amazing! Well done and thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a easy metod using jQuery,
I hope that's what you asked

```js
$("#tStartSelect").on("change", function () {
            if($("#tStartSelect").val() <= 22){
                $("#tEndSelect").val(Number($("#tStartSelect").val()) + 1);
            }else{
                $("#tEndSelect").val("0");
            }
        });
        $("#tEndSelect").on("change", function () {
            if($("#tEndSelect").val() <= 23 && $("#tEndSelect").val() > 0){
                $("#tStartSelect").val(Number($("#tEndSelect").val()) - 1);
            }else{
                $("#tStartSelect").val("23");
            }
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="t_Start">
        <select id="tStartSelect" class="form-control">
            <option value="0">00:00</option>
            <option value="1">01:00</option>
            <option value="2">02:00</option>
            <option value="3">03:00</option>
            <option value="4">04:00</option>
            <option value="5">05:00</option>
            <option value="6">06:00</option>
            <option value="7">07:00</option>
            <option value="8">08:00</option>
            <option value="9">09:00</option>
            <option value="10">10:00</option>
            <option value="11">11:00</option>
            <option value="12">12:00</option>
            <option value="13">13:00</option>
            <option value="14">14:00</option>
            <option value="15">15:00</option>
            <option value="16">16:00</option>
            <option value="17">17:00</option>
            <option value="18">18:00</option>
            <option value="19">19:00</option>
            <option value="20">20:00</option>
            <option value="21">21:00</option>
            <option value="22">22:00</option>
            <option value="23">23:00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="t_End">
        <select id="tEndSelect" class="form-control">
            <option value="1">01:00</option>
            <option value="2">02:00</option>
            <option value="3">03:00</option>
            <option value="4">04:00</option>
            <option value="5">05:00</option>
            <option value="6">06:00</option>
            <option value="7">07:00</option>
            <option value="8">08:00</option>
            <option value="9">09:00</option>
            <option value="10">10:00</option>
            <option value="11">11:00</option>
            <option value="12">12:00</option>
            <option value="13">13:00</option>
            <option value="14">14:00</option>
            <option value="15">15:00</option>
            <option value="16">16:00</option>
            <option value="17">17:00</option>
            <option value="18">18:00</option>
            <option value="19">19:00</option>
            <option value="20">20:00</option>
            <option value="21">21:00</option>
            <option value="22">22:00</option>
            <option value="23">23:00</option>
            <option value="0">00:00</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

I do not really know why you use these values(6, 10, 14 ...), for me is logical set a time value.

p.d.: sorry for my english.

Comment: Hey @Ivan, thanks for having a look. I like your code, but unfortunately I want to allow users to select time-spans of varying size. There is a reason for the 'odd' values that lies outside of this particular example.